# Deploying files to Identity Server Container

Tags: identity-server, docker

I am trying to configure a non-interactive client login in a Sitecore 10 container environment (https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/100/developer-tools/configure-a-non-interactive-client-login.html).  So I am going to have to deploy a config file to the /config folder of the identity server container.  I figure this should be no big deal.  I extend my docker-compose.override.xml file to support a volume/entrypoint on the id server:

```
id:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-id:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/id
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp1-cd:${SITECORE_VERSION}        
        TOOLING_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_TOOLS_REGISTRY}sitecore-docker-tools-assets:${TOOLS_VERSION}
        SOLUTION_IMAGE: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-solution:${VERSION:-latest}
    depends_on:
      - solution
    environment: 
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__DefaultClient__AllowedCorsOrigins__AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2: https://${HRZ_HOST}
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_DEPLOY_PATH}\identity:C:\deploy
    entrypoint: powershell -Command "& C:\tools\entrypoints\worker\Development.ps1"
```

Then I extend the id dockerfile

```
# escape=`

ARG BASE_IMAGE
ARG TOOLING_IMAGE
ARG SOLUTION_IMAGE

FROM ${SOLUTION_IMAGE} as solution
FROM ${TOOLING_IMAGE} as tooling

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

WORKDIR C:\config
COPY --from=solution \artifacts\Identity\ .\
```

I then docker-compose build and then dock-compose up -d.  Easy Peasy.

But for some reason when I bring up the ID container, I get the error:

```
& : The term 'C:\tools\entrypoints\worker\Development.ps1' is not recognized

as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the

spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is

correct and try again.

At line:1 char:3

+ & C:\tools\entrypoints\worker\Development.ps1

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (C:\tools\entryp...Development.p

s1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am confused.  I have the tooling image included and am using the correct powershell on the entrypoint, but it appears that the tools image is not recognized when trying to create the entrypoint.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dockerfile` is missing a command to copy the development tools and entrypoint scripts from the tooling image. You can explore your `identity` container and verify that the `tools` directory doesn't exist.

Fix this adding the command `COPY --from=tooling \tools\ \tools\` right after the `SHELL` command in your `dockerfile` build specs:

```
...
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

COPY --from=tooling \tools\ \tools\
...
```

Comment: That did it.  I knew it had to be something simple I was overlooking.  Thank you