# Error when starting CM and XConnect containers from docker examples custom-images

Tags: docker

I have cloned the Sitecore docker examples repository and used `docker-compose up` to start up the containers. Solr, Sql and Id containers are running successfully, however CM and XConnect are showing this error in the log files and failing to start:

```
The term 'C:toolsentrypointsiisDevelopment.ps1' is not recognized as the 
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & C:toolsentrypointsiisDevelopment.ps1
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:toolsentrypointsiisDevelopmen 
   t.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have also run the `sitecore-containers-prerequisites.ps1` previous to starting the containers and didn't see any issues. Based on the answer provided [Deploying files to Identity Server Container](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29994/deploying-files-to-identity-server-container) I've checked the CM and XConnect dockerfile and they contain the copy development tools and entrypoint command. I also have the `SitecoreDockerTools` module installed. Not sure what else to check, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you define the entrypoint command in the default docker-compose.yml file? Or are you using the overwrite compose file (that already defines the entrypoint command) when executing the `docker-compose up` command (ie. `docker-compose -f .\docker-compose.yml -f .\docker-compose.override.yml up`)?

Comment: I haven't changed the docker-compose files at all, left them as the ones from the repo.

Answer (score 19):

I fixed this by escaping the file path with double backslashes in docker-compose.override.yml i.e.

```
C:\\tools\\entrypoints\\iis\\Development.ps
```

```
entrypoint: powershell -Command "& C:\\tools\\entrypoints\\iis\\Development.ps1"
```

Running on Windows 11, the latest Docker desktop

Comment: If possible, please share how you are executing it. I am trying to follow the steps mentioned in the repository. So my change gets overridden. So, I get the same error.

Comment: After making the change described by @Bruce, rebuild the container from scratch with `docker compose build --no-cache` and the error will go away.

Comment: We had long time not updated Windows Docker Desktop because these errors showed up in the newer versions. Thanks to the solution, we can now use the most recent Docker Desktop.