# Error when building container with headless aspnetcore template

Tags: jss, docker

Im trying to use the aspnetcore template. When I try to run the up.ps1 script, it completes but gets stuck at the end. So I went into Docker desktop and saw this error in one of the images: [image]

After this nothing happens and the script stays stuck here:
[image]

Comment: Please add error as text in your question rather than the image.

Comment: Did you check this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30460/error-when-starting-cm-and-xconnect-containers-from-docker-examples-custom-image